# SQL Query with multiple databases

Tags: t-sql

I Have the following query

```
 EXECUTE sp_MSForEachDB
'USE ?; 
Select DB_NAME()AS DBName, count(DISTINCT TABLE.COLUMN) as "NEW_NAME"
  FROM [dbo].[TABLE]'
```

Which gives me the results I want but for every database in my connection I get a separate output.  Is there a way to put all these outputs from all the databases into one table.  Sorry If I am  not asking correctly sort of new to this...

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly this should work:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (DBName VARCHAR(250), NEW_NAME INT)

INSERT INTO #Temp 
EXECUTE sp_MSForEachDB
'USE ?; 
Select DB_NAME()AS DBName, count(DISTINCT TABLE.COLUMN) as "NEW_NAME"
  FROM [dbo].[TABLE]'


SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

Below is an example of how this would work. I have modified the query so that it can be run on my machine as I don't have the table [dbo].[TABLE] in my databases:

[image]